# False position method reached the MAX iterations limit

Tags: c, numerical-methods

I am trying to write a program to find roots of a continuous function using False Position Method. But, I am getting the same value of **c** again and again and same value is assigned to **a**, resulting in reaching the limit of MAX_ITER. How should I avoid this ? Am I not using the algorithm correctly ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

#define F(x) ((2*x)+1)
#define ERROR 0.00001
#define MAX_ITER 1000

float FalsePosition(float a, float b)
{   
    float c;
    int iter = 0;
    do
    {
        c = (b - F(b)) * (b - a) / (F(b) - F(a));

        printf("F(a): %f, F(b) : %f, F(c) : %f, a: %f, b : %f, c : %f\n", F(a), F(b), F(c), a, b, c);

        if((F(c) > 0 && F(a) > 0) || (F(c) < 0 && F(a) < 0))
        {
            a = c;
        }
        else
        {
            b=c;
        }

        iter++;
    }
    while(fabsf(a-b) > ERROR && iter < MAX_ITER);
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    float a = -2.5;
    float b = 2.5;

    printf("Finding root in the interval [%f, %f]\n", a, b);

    if((F(a)>0 && F(b)>0) || (F(a)<0 && F(b)<0))
    {
        printf("No root lie in the interval [%f, %f]", a, b);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The root is : %f\n", FalsePosition(a, b));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but don't use the ternary expression the way you're doing, it makes your code less readable and harder to maintain. Instead use a proper `if-else` statement. I also suggest you rename the macro `f` to `F`, macros names are commonly in all-caps, to distinguish them from functions. And is there a reason you don't use the standard [`fabsf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fabs) function?

Comment: One suggestion this condition `((F(c) > 0 && F(a) > 0) || (F(c) < 0 && F(a) < 0))` you can write it this way `(F(c) * F(a) > 0)`.

Comment: Did you read the wikipedia article? it's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula for `c` is wrong, it should be

```
c = b - (f(b) * (b - a)) / (f(b) - f(a));
```

see [here](http://mat.iitm.ac.in/home/sryedida/public_html/caimna/transcendental/bracketing%20methods/regula-falsi/regula-falsi.html)

To prevent reaching `MAX_ITER` iterations, you may want to watch the change in `c` something like

```
previousValue = c;
c = b - (f(b) * (b - a)) / (f(b) - f(a));
```

and then, the while condition would be

```
while ((fabs(previousValue - c) > ERROR) && (iter < MAX_ITER));
```

you can initialize `previousValue` to `a` befor beginig the loop.
And finally you should return `c` not `a`.

Comment: The formula for `c` in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_position_method) is wrong, though in [spanish wikepedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_la_regla_falsa) it is ok.

Comment: yes, I was going to write the same as soon as you posted your answer. Thanks.